# Can we post Questions for google users and should there be a Tag for them?

Tags: discussion

I am still new to the Beta and SE, and I'm puzzled.

Whats should I do when I have a question which I think of someone would Google for, but which I know the answer to? What dose SE say about that? Are these Questions OK if another person answers them first?

Do we need a "Google" tag?

Comment: As Bobson says in a comment further down Google already indexes stack exchange. There is no need to try and do anything to bring search traffic here and a tag would be meaningless. Google will index everything whether tagged or not and if the questions and answers are interesting enough people will come and read and some will stay...

Answer (score 10):

We definitely **shouldn't** post questions *just* because people are likely to google for them. We should post questions (and answers) because *they add to the corpus of knowledge on the Internet;* in other words, they *help someone learn*. Ideally, they should be useful to people [long after the person posting the question and answer are both gone](http://xkcd.com/979/) from the site.

And we *certainly* shouldn't use a specific tag for questions "meant to be found through a search engine". What would the value of that tag be?

**However,** if you have a question that you feel is on topic for the site, then there is no reason why you can't ask it. If you happen to know the answer as well, there is a checkbox below the question body field which allows you to [**post a self-answer**](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) at the same time that you post the question. Doing so is allowed and even encouraged on the Stack Exchange network, subject to the question being on topic and a good question in the first place.

Do note that self-answers *tend* to be judged more harshly than answers posted to other peoples' questions, so if you do this, really put time into both the question and answer and make sure they are both as good as you can possibly make them.

Comment: But. Is that not exactly what SE is layed out for? I always thought that the Google searches are the highest part of the visits.

Comment: @Fulli Search engine traffic is a large source of traffic for a healthy site, but that doesn't mean that search engine traffic should be the motivator for posting questions. You should post questions because you want an answer, not because someone else might.

Comment: @Fulli ultimately we hope *all* our excellent questions and answers will be found by Googlers.

Comment: Google's also *very* good about indexing SE sites.  If you ask a question, it'll start showing up in search results within an hour or two, usually.  So ask a good question and google will start sending traffic at it.